# adding treeNode to antdesign tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview

I wrote this Code and I want to add 3 icons per each record in this antDesign tree.so what should I do?
i tried lots of ways but idk what is the solution

```
const ChartMaker = ({ chart }) => {
    const [parentId, setParentId] = useState(null)
    const [childId, setChildtId] = useState(null)

    const flattenData = (data) => {
        if (!data) return [];
        return data.map((item) => ({
            title: item.title,
            key: item.id,
            children: flattenData(item.childs, flattenData(item.child))
        }));
    };
    const treeData = flattenData(chart);

    const onSelect = (selectedKeys) => {
        setChildtId(selectedKeys)
    };
    const onExpand = (keys) => {
        setParentId(keys)
    };
    console.log("parent", parentId, "child", childId);
    return (
        <Tree
            showLine
            switcherIcon={<DownOutlined />}
            onSelect={onSelect}
            onExpand={onExpand}
            treeData={treeData}
        >
            <TreeNode icon={<DeleteOutlined />} />
        </Tree>
    );
};
export default ChartMaker;
```

Comment: What issue you facing here? You want to show delete icon with childs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Ant Design [docs](https://ant.design/components/tree), you have to pass a props in tree component to show icons along side each child in the tree. For this, lets modify the server data to include icon property like so:

```
const flattenData = (data) => {
    if (!data) return [];
    return data.map((item) => ({
        title: item.title,
        key: item.id,
        // Add an Icon property here for childs
        icon: item.childs ? <FolderOutlined /> : item.child ? <FolderOutlined /> : <DeleteOutlined />, 
        children: flattenData(item.childs, flattenData(item.child))
    }));
};
```

Your component Tree should look like this:

```
return (
    <Tree
        showLine
        switcherIcon={<DownOutlined />}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        onExpand={onExpand}
        treeData={treeData}
    >
    </Tree>
);
```

And with this, you should see relevant icons in the component tree.

Comment: actually its not working

Comment: Did you updated your Component tree? Let me update the code above to show you how.

Comment: Let me know if you have made the exact changes